# Django - Forloop Undefined

Tags: django, undefined, counter

I have been trying to draw a chess board using Django, Python, CSS, and HTML. To do this, I need to keep track of the number of iterations in my for loop. I read through [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for) and saw that I should use `forloop.counter`.

When I used `forloop.counter` in my program, I received a `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError` which stated that `forloop` was undefined. I uninstalled and reinstalled Django 1.11.5 in my IDE and received the same error. I installed Django's development version and received the same error.

I checked my usage of `forloop.counter` in a separate test program, and I still received an error saying that `forloop` was undefined.

Is there an error with Django itself? Thank you.

Here is the test program:

```
<div id="container">
   {% block main %}
        {% for item in length %}
            <p>{{ forloop.counter }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
   {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That error message shows that you are using Jinja2 as the template engine rather than Django's own template language. You must have configured this explicitly in your settings file.

In Jinja2, you use `{{ loop.index }}` - see [the documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#for).

Unless you have a very good reason though, you should probably revert to the standard Django templates setting.

Comment: Thank you. How do I revert back to the standard Django templates?

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#configuration).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Doesn't Jinja2 carry significant performance advantages? https://www.dyspatch.io/blog/python-templating-performance-showdown-django-vs-jinja/